# Elliptic regularity in a weird domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

I am curious about the regularity of the solution in $H^1$ of the following PDE: In $\mathbb{R}^n$ let $B = B(0, 1)$, $\Sigma = \{x_n = 0\}$ and $T = B(0, 1/2) \cap \Sigma$. Consider
\begin{align} 
\Delta u &= 0 \text{ in } B_+ \cup B_- \cup T \\ u &= 1 \text{ on } \partial B \setminus \Sigma \\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} &= 0 \text{ on both sides of } B \cap (\Sigma \setminus \bar{T})
\end{align}
where $B_+$ and $B_+$ are the upper and lower half-balls respectively. In other words, the domain consists of two open half-balls touching along an $(n - 1)$-dimensional ball in their flat surfaces.

The variational formulation is as follows: $$ \int_B \nabla u \nabla v \, dx = 0$$ for all $v \in H^1(B_+ \cup B_- \cup T)$ having trace equal to $0$ on $\partial B \setminus \Sigma$.

By the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797499/regularity-of-solutions-to-poissons-equation-on-part-of-the-boundary/4799271#4799271), the solution will be smooth everywhere on the boundary except perhaps on the round edges of the half-balls. Can we say that the solution is smooth up to the boundary?

Comment: From standard elliptic regularity theory a solution $u$ to your problem will be smooth in $\overline B \setminus \Sigma$ i.e. in $B$ and up to the boundary except from across $\Sigma$. I can explain why this in more detail if you would like

Comment: What isn't clear to me is how you have Neumann condition. In order have this you require that $u$ $C^1$ across $B \cap (\Sigma \setminus \overline T)$ we is not obvious. Indeed, this doesn't immediately follow from standard regularity theory since $B \cap (\Sigma \setminus \overline T)$ is not $C^k$ for any $k$

Comment: @JackT Regularity on $\bar{B} \setminus \Sigma$ is clear to me. You say $B \cap (\Sigma \setminus \bar{T})$ is not $C^k$ but it's simply an annulus, so it's $C^\infty$, no? Actually, shouldn't $u$ be smooth up to the boundary on $B \setminus K$, where $K$ is a compact neighborhood of $\partial B \cap \Sigma$? My concern is with the behavior on $\partial B \cap \Sigma$.

Comment: Well, it depends on what is meant by $C^k$. When you say it’s an annulus, it’s an annulus in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ not $\mathbb R^n$, so when you say $\Sigma \setminus \overline T$ is smooth because an annulus is smooth you’re saying $\partial (\Sigma \setminus \overline T)$ is smooth as a subset of $\mathbb R^{n-1}$.

Comment: Moreover, since $\Sigma \setminus \overline T$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^{n-1}$, it’s a smooth manifold. However, my issue is that in every PDE book I’ve ever read the definition of $C^k$ boundary is that the set is locally contained on one side of the graph of $C^k$ function i.e. is the epigraph of a $C^k$ function. This is not the case here - your set touches $\Sigma \setminus \overline T$ from both sides

Comment: The implications for the regularity are this: your function will still be smooth approaching from both sides (i.e. will extend to a $C^\infty$ function), however, the extensions may not agree, so this would have to be checked carefully